# replacement on xargs variable returns empty string

Tags: string, bash, sed, replace, xargs

I need to search for XML files inside a directory tree and create links for them on another directory (staging_ojs_pootle), naming these links with the file path (replacing slashes per dots).

the bash command is not working, I got stuck on the replacement part. Seems like the variable from xargs, named 'file', is not accessible inside the replacement code `(${file/\//.})`

```
find directory/ -name '*.xml' | xargs  -I 'file' echo "ln" file staging_ojs_pootle/${file/\//.}
```

The replacement inside ${} result gives me an empty string.

Tried using sed but regular expressions were replacing all or just the last slash :/

```
 find directory/ -name '*.xml' | xargs  -I 'file' echo "ln" file staging_ojs_pootle/file |sed -e '/^ln/s/\(staging_ojs_pootle.*\)[\/]\(.*\)/\1.\2/g'
```

regards

Comment: `file` isn't the name of a shell variable, it's a placeholder that gets replaced by xargs with the name of the XML file it's processing. So you can't use shell variable substitution commands like `${file...}` on it. If you show us some sample input and expected output we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ find directory/ -name '*.xml' |sed -r 'h;s|/|.|g;G;s|([^\n]+)\n(.+)|ln \2 staging_ojs_pootle/\1|e'
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/test
$ touch {1,2,3,4}.xml
# use /tmp/test as staging_ojs_pootle
$ find /tmp/test -name '*.xml' |sed -r 'h;s|/|.|g;G;s|([^\n]+)\n(.+)|ln \2 /tmp/test/\1|e'
$ ls -al /tmp/test
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jun 15 13:09 .
drwxrwxrwt. 9 root root 4096 Jun 15 11:45 ..
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 2.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 3.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 4.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 .tmp.test.1.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 .tmp.test.2.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 .tmp.test.3.xml
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root    0 Jun 15 11:45 .tmp.test.4.xml
# if don NOT use the e modifier of s command, we can get the final command
$ find /tmp/test -name '*.xml' |sed -r 'h;s|/|.|g;G;s|([^\n]+)\n(.+)|ln \2 /tmp/test/\1|' 
ln /tmp/test/1.xml /tmp/test/.tmp.test.1.xml
ln /tmp/test/2.xml /tmp/test/.tmp.test.2.xml
ln /tmp/test/3.xml /tmp/test/.tmp.test.3.xml
ln /tmp/test/4.xml /tmp/test/.tmp.test.4.xml
```

Explains:

1. for each xml file, use `h` to keep the origin filename in `hold space`.
2. the use `s|/|.|g` to substitute all `/` to `.` for xml filename.
3. use `G` to append the `hold space` to `pattern space`, then `pattern space` is `CHANGED_FILENAME\nORIGIN_FILENAME`.
4. use `s|([^\n]+)\n(.+)|ln \2 staging_ojs_pootle/\1|e'` to merge the command with `CHANGED_FILENAME` and `ORIGIN_FILENAME`, then use `e` modifier of s command to execute the command assembled above, which will do the actual works.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that the names of your XML files do not contain any word-splitting characters, you can use something like:

```
find directory -name "*.xml" | sed 'p;s/\//./' | xargs -n2 echo ln
```